# Three.js installation and modules not working on a localhost

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I hope that there are some experienced people on this platform who'd be willing to help me with my three.js problem.

My current problem is this, I can't seem to properly run the three.js library on my localhost, all I get is a white screen.
My files:

[image: 1]

My Javascript code:

```
import * as THREE from 'three.js-master/three.js';
import { OrbitControls } from "three.js-master/examples/OrbitControls.js";

const scene = new THREE.Scene(); //generate scene
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 ); //generate camera

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer(); //launch renderer using WebGl
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 5;
const controls = new OrbitControls( camera, renderer.domElement );

const animate = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );

    cube.rotation.x += 0.05;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
};

animate();
```

And my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>EMBÄR</title>
<link src="style.css" type="stylesheet"> 
</head>
<body>
<script src = "three.js" type="module"></script>
<script src="Main.js" type="module"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now, this just gives a white screen all the time, but I've managed to use the link:
https://unpkg.com/three/build/three.module.js (instead of three.js-master/three.js)  in combination with:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.114/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js (instead of three.js-master/examples/OrbitControls.js)
to successfully run the script, but this really isn't a solution, since I had to search for days to find these links, and it surely isn't efficient if I want to include more modules besides these.

It'd be awesome if someone knew the answer, but please, don't feel pressured to do a lot of research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML should look like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>EMBÄR</title>
      <link src="style.css" type="stylesheet">
      <!-- Import maps polyfill -->
      <!-- Remove this when import maps will be widely supported -->
      <script async src="https://unpkg.com/es-module-shims@1.3.6/dist/es-module-shims.js"></script>
      <script type="importmap">
         {
            "imports": {
                "three": "./three.js-master/build/three.module.js",
                "three/addons/": "./three.js-master/examples/jsm/"
            }
         }
      </script>
      <script src="Main.js" type="module"> </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   </body>
</html>
```

In your `Main.js` file, use the following imports:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/addons/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

The imports in your JS should look exactly like the ones from the [official examples](https://threejs.org/examples/). The only thing that differs is the import map. In your case, you refer to your locally hosted version of the `three.js` repo. Keep in mind to always use the `module.js` version of `three.js`. Not the UMD build.

You find more information about the setup/installation of `three.js` in this [guide](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Installation).